# Fix dataframe values by values from second dataframe with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with the same shapes and I'd like to fix first by values from second one(based on some condition):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,2,3], 'b' : [11,22,33], 'c' : [111,222,333]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [0,-1,-1], 'b' : [-1,-1,-1], 'c' : [1,2,-1]})
```

The condition is the following: I replace value in df1 on corresponding value from df2 if last is not -1. As result I should receive the following output:

```
   a   b   c
0  0   11  1
1  2   22  2
2  3   33  333
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

```
df1.update(df2[df2.ne(-1)])

print (df1)

     a   b      c
0  0.0  11    1.0
1  2.0  22    2.0
2  3.0  33  333.0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df1[df2.eq(-1)].fillna(df2)
```

output

```
     a   b      c
0  0.0  11    1.0
1  2.0  22    2.0
2  3.0  33  333.0
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.mask`:

```
df1.mask(df2.ne(-1), df2)
```

Output:

```
   a   b    c
0  0  11    1
1  2  22    2
2  3  33  333
```